# AVPlayer failed state

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I am working on iOS application that does hls streaming. I also have mac version of it. The application works fine on Mac but on iOS the player goes to failed state around the time it asked for content.

Here is the error information I get from the player.

```
400691600095 [3CED718C] DEBUG Apple: [MyMovieView.m:1996] backtrace: (
    0   MyApp                             0x007f9333 -[MyMovieView(Private) handleNewLoadState:] + 362
    1   MyApp                             0x007f6f93 -[MyMovieView observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] + 466
    2   Foundation                          0x306b8c8f <redacted> + 34
    3   Foundation                          0x306b8bdb <redacted> + 402
    4   Foundation                          0x306b8c8f <redacted> + 34
    5   Foundation                          0x306b8bdb <redacted> + 402
    6   Foundation                          0x306965d1 <redacted> + 272
    7   Foundation                          0x30696275 <redacted> + 344
    8   Foundation                          0x306828cd <redacted> + 88
    9   AVFoundation                        0x2ec1ad81 <redacted> + 44
    10  AVFoundation                        0x2ec1d097 <redacted> + 182
    11  AVFoundation                        0x2ec28ee5 <redacted> + 2524
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x3ae11833 <redacted> + 10
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x3ae1181f <redacted> + 22
    14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x3ae1849f <redacted> + 278
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x2fd2c8f1 <redacted> + 8
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x2fd2b1c5 <redacted> + 1300
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x2fc95f4f CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x2fc95d33 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x34bbb663 GSEventRunModal + 138
    20  UIKit                               0x325e116d UIApplicationMain + 1136
    21  MyApp                             0x0000ad71 main + 192
    22  libdyld.dylib                       0x3ae36ab7 <redacted> + 2
)
1400691600097 [3CED718C] DEBUG Apple: [MyMovieView.m:2006] <MyAVAssetProxy: 0x197eb70> <AVURLAsset: 0x670b270, URL = http://127.0.0.1:12000/stream/vplaylist.m3u8?id=192.168.1.114-7cf95af1535e80c4a77c>
1400691600102 [3CED718C] DEBUG Apple: [MyMovieView.m:2008] error during movie playback: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "**unsupported URL**" UserInfo=0x6dd1cc0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x6dd1650 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -1002.)", NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL} (null)
1400691600102 [3CED718C] DEBUG Apple: [MyMovieView.m:2108] additional info for playback error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo=0x6dd1cc0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x6dd1650 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -1002.)", NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL}: (null)
1400691600103 [3CED718C] DEBUG Apple: [MyMovieView.m:1506] Observing <AVPlayerLayer: 0x670e730>, player.rate
1400691600103 [3CED718C] DEBUG Apple: [MyMovieView.m:1506] Observing <AVPlayerLayer: 0x670e730>, player.currentItem.status
1400691600104 [3CED718C] DEBUG Apple: [MyMovieView.m:1993] load state changed from unknown to unknown
1400691600113 [3CED718C] DEBUG Apple: [PlaybackViewController.m:1370] playback failed: {
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=51 \"unsupported URL\" UserInfo=0x6dd1cc0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x6dd1650 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (OSStatus error -1002.)\", NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL}";
```

Its my limitation that I cannot reveal more than this but am trying to find out what could be wrong. Why the player is saying 'unsupported Url' The player request for vplaylist, playlist and content were successful. I also see that the HTTP proxy has started getting the first segment, but for some reason the player goes to failed state while its getting the segment data.

I know that there are differences between hls streaming on Mac and iOS, I am trying to figure those out. I am new to AVFoundation :)

Any help would be grateful.

Comment: Hey dev, Were you able to figure out the issue? I'm doing the same implementation as you did and am stuck with the same error. Can you please help me on this?

Comment: Madala, as far as I remember there was some issue in the playlist using custom protocol and its implementation on Mac and iOS for me.

Comment: I'm not using any custom protocol in the playlist. They are all http. But still I get this error.

Comment: Hi @Madala, I'm getting the same problem. Were you ever able to solve it?